# MySQL SELECT SUM(Column) and SELECT * Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, select

Trying to write statement where in single statement select all (`*`) and sum one column from the same database and the same table, depending on conditions.

Wrote such statement (based on this [Multiple select statements in Single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775168/multiple-select-statements-in-single-query))

`SELECT ( SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM 2_1_journal), ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ? )`

I understand that `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM 2_1_journal` will sum all values in column `Amount` (not based on codition).

But at first want to understand what is correct statement

With above statement get error `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Can not understand error message. From advice here [MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046838/mysql-operand-should-contain-1-columns) understand that subquery `SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ?` must select only one column?

Tried to change statement to this `SELECT ( SELECT * FROM 2_1_journal WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ? ), ( SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM 2_1_journal)`, but get the same error...

What would be correct statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM 2_1_journal)
  FROM 2_1_journal
 WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ?
```

This selects sums up `Amount` from the *entire* table and "appends" all rows where `TransactionPartnerName` is the parameter you bind in the client code.

If you want to limit the sum to the same criteria as the rows you select, just include it:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM 2_1_journal WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ?)
  FROM 2_1_journal
 WHERE TransactionPartnerName = ?
```

A whole different thing: table names like `2_1_journal` are strong indicators of a broken database design. If you can redo it, you should look into how to normalize the database properly. It is most likely pay back many times over.

**With regard to normalization (added later):**

Since the current design uses keys in table names (such as the `2` and `1` in `2_1_journal`), I'll quickly illustrate how I think you can vastly improve that design. Lets say that the table `2_1_journal` has the following data (I'm just guessing here because the tables haven't been described anywhere yet):

```
title | posted     | content
------+------------+-----------------
Yes!  | 2013-01-01 | This is just a test
2nd   | 2013-01-02 | Another test
```

This stuff belongs to user `2` in company `1`. But hey! If you look at the rows, the fact that this data belongs to user `2` in company `1` is nowhere to be found.

The problem is that this design violates one of the most basic principles of database design: don't use keys in object (here: table) names. A clear indication that something is very wrong is if you have to create new tables if something new is added. In this case, adding a new user or a new company requires adding new tables.

This issue is easilly fixed. Create *one* table named `journal`. Next, use the same columns, but add another two:

```
company | user | title | posted     | content
--------+------+-------+------------+-----------------
      1 |    2 | Yes!  | 2013-01-01 | This is just a test
      1 |    2 | 2nd   | 2013-01-02 | Another test
```

Doing it like this means:

- You never add or modify tables unless the application changes.
- Doing joins across companies or users (and anything else that used to be part of the table naming scheme is now possible with a single, fairly simple select statement).
- Enforcing integrity is easy - if you upgrade the application and want to change the tables, the changes doesn't have to be repeated for each company and user. More importantly, this lowers the risk of having the application get out of sync with the tables in the database (such as adding the field `comments` to all `x_y_journal` tables, but forgetting `5313_4324_journal` causing the application to break *only* when user `5313` logs in. This is the kind of problem you don't want to deal with.

I am not writing this because it is a matter of personal taste. Databases are just designed to handle tables that are laid out as I describe above. The design where you use object keys as part of table names has a host of other problems associated with it that are very hard to deal with.

Comment: Regarding table names is problem related with `_`? Such table names are because: i) table: `users` and each user has his own number (for example, number two). ii) then table number `2_` is related only with particular user. In this table are included companies, related with particular user and companies are numbered, like 1, 2, 3, 4; iii) for each company there are several tables, like, journal, employees, warehouse. So 2_1_journal means journal for user No 2, company No 1. I think about table names and this was solution I choose....

Comment: Did you consider adding a column named ``Company`` to the tables ``like``, ``journal`` and so forth? What you are doing is highly unconventional and will probably cause problems some time further down the road.

Comment: You can see tutorials about normalization here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygfikznRjpw and http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/.

Comment: You mean instead of `2_1_journal` to use `2CompanyJournal`? Thanks for info I will think about other solution. When I was thinking about naming, wanted to get that all table names would be unique and at the moment I have forgotten (not sure), but suppose `2` or number without `_` or something like that is not allowed. If I use `UsernameCompanynameJournal` then table names would be not unique, because different users can use the same usernames (like here http://www.freshbooks.com/)

Comment: No. I am not suggesting a name as you write it above. I'll add a note wrt. normalization to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. In any case I have to work for many months to get all ready. Will change table naming...

Comment: The changes that I am suggesting above will save you a lot of time in the long run. Believe me :)