# SQL: Performing a calculation on columns from two select statements in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select information from two unrelated SQL tables (formed by separate SQL queries) to give me one table with four columns: one as an identifier, one for values from the first table, one for values from the second table, and one for a calculation between them.

A simplified example is:

tblSold

```
 Shop name | items sold
 Shop A    | 100   
 Shop B    | 50    
 Shop C    | 75    
 Shop D    | 80
```

tblReturned

```
  Shop name | Items returned
  Shop A    | 10
  Shop B    | 5   
  Shop C    | 7 
  Shop D    | 8
```

And i'm trying to get a table that looks like this

```
  Shop name | items sold | items returned | net (sold - returned)
  Shop A    | 100        | 10             | 90
  Shop B    | 50         | 5              | 45
  Shop C    | 75         | 7              | 68
  Shop D    | 80         | 8              | 72
```

In the above case, tblSold comes from a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.sold) 
FROM global
INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
GROUP BY shopname
```

And tblReturned comes from a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.returned) 
FROM global
INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
WHERE stock.datereturned > 1.01.2010
GROUP BY shopname
```

From this previous question [SQL: Two select statements in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979008/sql-two-(select-statements-in-one-query) I got the following query:

```
(SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.sold) 
FROM global
INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
GROUP BY shopname)

UNION

(SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.returned) 
FROM global
INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
WHERE stock.datereturned > 1.01.2010
GROUP BY shopname)
```

Which got me a table with only two columns, and no way to make the calculation. Is there a way to join these in some manner to make it work?

Comment: Please specify which product you are using.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - sorry for the error. It's Postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT g.shopname, COUNT(s.sold),
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.datereturned > '2010-01-01' AND s.returned IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as returned,
       (COUNT(s.sold) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN s.datereturned > '2010-01-01' AND s.returned IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ) as net
FROM global INNER JOIN
     stock
     ON g.id = s.shop
GROUP BY g.shopname;
```

Having the date logic only apply to returns is strange.  Also, I am guessing, though, that you want `SUM()` of the inventory and not `COUNT()`.  So this may produce more accurate results:

```
SELECT g.shopname, SUM(s.sold) as items_sold,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.datereturned > '2010-01-01' THEN s.returned ELSE 0 END) as items_returned,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.datereturned > '2010-01-01' THEN s.items_sold - s.returned
                ELSE s.items_sold END)
FROM global INNER JOIN
     stock
     ON g.id = s.shop
GROUP BY g.shopname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.shopname,
       t1.items_sold,
       t2.items_returned,(t1.items_sold-t2.items_returned) AS NET 
FROM (SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.sold) as items_sold
      FROM global
      INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
      GROUP BY shopname) t1
INNER JOIN  (SELECT global.shopname, COUNT(stock.returned) as items_returned
             FROM global
             INNER JOIN  stock ON global.id = stock.shop
             WHERE stock.datereturned > '2010-01-01'
             GROUP BY shopname) t2
ON t1.shopname = t2.shopname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH tblSold AS (
    SELECT
      global.shopname,
      COUNT(stock.sold) AS sold
    FROM global
      INNER JOIN stock ON global.id = stock.shop
    GROUP BY shopname),
    tblReturned AS (
      SELECT
        global.shopname,
        COUNT(stock.returned) AS returned
      FROM global
        INNER JOIN stock ON global.id = stock.shop
      WHERE stock.datereturned > '1.01.2010'
      GROUP BY shopname)
SELECT
  shopname,
  sold,
  returned,
  sold - returned
FROM tblSold
  INNER JOIN tblReturned USING (shopname);
```