# How to run two SQL queries using only one statement in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
app.get("/total", function(req,res){
var q = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS new FROM voters_detail WHERE parties LIKE '%BJP%'";
connection.query(q, function(err, results){
    if(err) throw err;
    var hello = results[0].new;
    res.send("BJP Was Voted By " + hello + " People");
});
```

});

I want to add and new query which says that;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters_detail WHERE parties LIKE '%Congress';
```

And then I want that it also displays on the **\total** page when I call this route on my server.

Help me out, please!

Comment: I think your actual problem is more related to SQL rather than Node.js: "How to make two select statements in one query". An answer can be found e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979008/sql-two-select-statements-in-one-query .

Comment: What exactly keeps you from performing a second query?

Comment: No, the solution which you provides says that how to select 2 queries from 2 different tables at once. But I want to select 2 queries means I want to show on the server that ........ people voted this party and ....... people voted this party but this is not running. @newBee

Comment: There is no difference wether or not you do two selects from two tables or from just one: `SELECT 'bjp' as party, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM voters_detail WHERE parties LIKE '%BJP%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'congress' as party, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM voters_detail WHERE parties LIKE '%Congress';`

Comment: @newBee pls see the answer section of this question, I have pasted what I have tried. Help pls!

Comment: please update your question by APPENDING it to your original question. Do not, however, replace what you have already written. Otherwise it will be very hard for anyone to understand the answers/comments so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you should make a file of xyz.sql and then write the two queries in that file and then parse it to the code.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should that be better than firing two queries?

Comment: Moving the sql queries to a file does not help you with writing the correct query. Not sure why this is considered the correct answer?!

Comment: He asked about to run two queries in a single file, I just told him that.