# Optimize 3 MYSQL Queries to one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

My Page has over 30mio Views per Day and i can't cache the Page (The data must always be up-to-date).

I have three MYSQL Queries which I would like to summarize.
Is this possible?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `meta_holdings` 
INNER JOIN coins ON coins.cmc_id = meta_holdings.cmc_id
WHERE  `userId` = $userId
LIMIT 0 , 999

SELECT * 
FROM  `meta_watchlist` 
INNER JOIN coins ON coins.cmc_id = meta_watchlist.cmc_id
WHERE  `userId` = $userId
LIMIT 0 , 999

SELECT * 
FROM  `coins` 
ORDER BY  `coins`.`rank` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Glad to have any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple select statements in Single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775168/multiple-select-statements-in-single-query)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of that to me. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 30M hits a day is 350 hits/s on average, surely you can cache for 1 second to reduce the unique hits to 85K

Answer (score 1):

A single query returns a single data set. By seeing your three queries, it looks like you need three data sets. You cannot achieve the same functionalities by mearging the queries. So the way it looks should be okay unless you have changed your requirements. Alternatively you can look into MySQL's internal cache.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this ..

```
SELECT * FROM  `meta_holdings` INNER JOIN coins ON coins.cmc_id = meta_holdings.cmc_id WHERE  `userId` = $userId LIMIT 0 , 999 
UNION
SELECT * FROM  `meta_watchlist` INNER JOIN coins ON coins.cmc_id = meta_watchlist.cmc_id WHERE  `userId` = $userId LIMIT 0 , 999
UNION
SELECT * FROM  `coins` ORDER BY  `coins`.`rank` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query if you are trying to find the top 30 rankings of **coins** table data of  along with meta_holdings,meta_watchlist details -

```
SELECT * FROM  coins 
INNER JOIN meta_holdings ON coins.cmc_id = meta_holdings.cmc_id
INNER JOIN meta_watchlist ON coins.cmc_id = meta_watchlist.cmc_id
WHERE  meta_holdings.userId = $userId and meta_watchlist.userId = $userId
ORDER BY  `coins`.`rank` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'holdings.userId' in 'where clause'