# Many select statement from multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to display a data table with a query using many selects and various conditions, I've tried it but the result is that each column content keeps repeating and many duplicates.

I hope someone can help solve my problem

the result of my query :

[image]

While the result I want is as follows :

| agent | blast | replied | responded | awaiting | no_reply |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry |  |  |  |  |  |
| Andrian | 50 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 5 |
| James | 40 | 20 | 15 | 6 | 8 |
| Superadmin | 100 | 20 | 10 | 10 | 50 |

I tried :

```sql
SELECT t1.agent, 
       t2.blast,
       t3.replied,
       t4.responded,
       t5.awaiting,
       t6.no_reply
FROM   (SELECT realname AS agent
        FROM user) AS t1 -- this is for agent,
       (SELECT count(*) AS blast 
        FROM message_thread 
        right join user
        on message_thread.agent_id = user.id
        right join message
        on message_thread.id = message.message_thread_id
        where message.status = 'sent'
        group by message_thread.agent_id) AS t2 -- this is for blast,
       (select count(*) as replied
        from message_thread
        right join user
        on message_thread.agent_id = user.id
        right join message
        on message_thread.id = message.message_thread_id
        where message.status = 'delivered'
        group by message_thread.agent_id) AS t3 -- this is for replied,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT a.id) AS responded
        FROM message_thread a 
        right join user
        on a.agent_id = user.id
        WHERE 
        EXISTS(
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread b 
           right join message e
           on b.id = e.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = b.id
           AND e.status = 'sent'
        ) and exists (
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread c 
           right join message f
           on c.id = f.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = c.id
           AND f.status = ''
        )and exists(
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread d 
           right join message g
           on d.id = g.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = d.id
           AND g.status = 'delivered'
        )
        group by a.agent_id) AS t4 -- this is for responded,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT a.id) AS awaiting
        FROM message_thread a 
        right join user
        on a.agent_id = user.id
        WHERE 
        EXISTS(
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread b 
           right join message e
           on b.id = e.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = b.id
           AND e.status = 'sent'
        )and not exists (
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread c 
           right join message f
           on c.id = f.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = c.id
           AND f.status = ''
        )and exists(
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread d 
           right join message g
           on d.id = g.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = d.id
           AND g.status = 'delivered'
        )
        group by a.agent_id) AS t5 -- this is for awaiting,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT a.id) AS no_reply
        FROM message_thread a 
        right join user
        on a.agent_id = user.id
        WHERE not exists(
           SELECT 1 FROM message_thread d 
           right join message g
           on d.id = g.message_thread_id
           WHERE a.id = d.id
           AND g.status = 'delivered'
        )
        group by a.agent_id) AS t6 -- this is for no_reply
```

Comment: Dare I ask, how long does your query take to run?

Comment: Your query is using the old-style (i.e. 1980s-era, **bad-style**) of JOINs by using commas in the `FROM` clause. You need to change your query to use modern-style (i.e. post-1992) 
explicit `JOIN`s.

Comment: 22 seconds :') , I tried the query from this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775168/multiple-select-statements-in-single-query)
can you help me

Comment: previously I've tried using union and union all, but it only produces one column

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: can you explain it? please @Akina

Comment: Investigate [existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+conditional+aggregation+pivot)